# Closing or closed in this case

Tags: continuous

Tomorrow, the store is "**closing/closed**" for two weeks hopefully it will reopen soon after .

I think both can fit because the closing is temporary  so continuous should fit

Comment: _Tomorrow the store is closing for two weeks_ OR _The store will be closed for two weeks from tomorrow_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say either:

> Tomorrow, the store is closing for two weeks.
>
> Beginning tomorrow, the store will be closed for two weeks.

The last part doesn't seem to fit, however. By using "hopefully," you've introduced doubt. But the doubt is connected to the reopening, and if you've said that it's only closing for two weeks, why wouldn't it open again? Perhaps the doubt belongs with the two week period rather than the reopening? For example:

> The store is closing for renovations beginning tomorrow. Hopefully it won't take more than two weeks.